# Is there a better way to get exact screen position of objects in windowed mode?

Tags: android, coordinates, android-view

Trying to move some `ImageView` objects around in relation to other `ImageView` objects but the coordinates I am getting from `getLocationOnScreen(int[])` do not match what is on the screen.  Also one object is being placed above the "parent" and the other is being placed below the "parent".  adjusting the height of app_bar_main affects the positioning as well.  I'm having a hard time with this.  All I want is one object to be placed in the middle of the other...  Please help.

FYI x coord is working fine in portrait and LANDSCAPE oddly enough.

Both markers use the same code to center themselves.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caMYk.jpg)

```
//Centers the position marker on the slider graphic
public void centerSlider(){
    ImageView sliderPosition = (ImageView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.iv_slider_position);
    int posXY[] = new int[2];
    rootview.findViewById(R.id.iv_slider).getLocationOnScreen(posXY);
    int centerX = posXY[0] + ((rootview.findViewById(R.id.iv_slider)).getWidth() / 2);
    int centerY = posXY[1] - ((rootview.findViewById(R.id.iv_slider)).getHeight() / 2);
    sliderPosition.setX(centerX - (rootview.findViewById(R.id.iv_slider_position).getWidth() / 2));
    sliderPosition.setY(centerY - (rootview.findViewById(R.id.iv_slider_position).getHeight() / 2));
}
```

This is the Layout

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/joystick3"
    android:id="@+id/iv_joystick"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

<ImageView
    ads:srcCompat="@drawable/ball"
    android:id="@+id/iv_joystick_position"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/iv_joystick"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iv_joystick"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="false" />

<GridLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/live_damp_start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_damp_start"
        android:textColor="@color/live_control_text_ui"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2" />

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sb_damp_start"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/live_damp_end"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_damp_end"
        android:textColor="@color/live_control_text_ui"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2" />

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sb_damp_end"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/invert"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:textColor="@color/live_control_text_ui"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="4" />

    <CheckBox
        android:text="@string/pan"
        android:textColor="@color/live_control_text_ui"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <CheckBox
        android:text="@string/tilt"
        android:textColor="@color/live_control_text_ui"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <CheckBox
        android:text="@string/slide"
        android:textColor="@color/live_control_text_ui"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/return_center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:textColor="@color/live_control_text_ui"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:text="@string/pan"
        android:textColor="@color/live_control_text_ui"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:text="@string/tilt"
        android:textColor="@color/live_control_text_ui"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:text="@string/slide"
        android:textColor="@color/live_control_text_ui"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox6"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

</GridLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/slider3"
    android:id="@+id/iv_slider"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ad_view"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp" />

<ImageView
    ads:srcCompat="@drawable/ball"
    android:id="@+id/iv_slider_position"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/iv_slider"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iv_slider"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use `android:layout_gravity` then

Comment: Unless I can make an ImageView the parent of an ImageView, it won't work.  I looked into this option.  Is there a container that won't cause the "parent" image to scale beyond the edge of the screen when wrapped around it?

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually?  maybe some image describing?

Comment: I posted a picture look for the link above^  Basically the Red dot needs to return to center of the slider and joystick background graphic `onTouch` = `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`

The output of the code I posted is shown in the picture.  It's like I'm receiving arbitrary numbers.

Comment: So I figured out what's going on...
I guess Android gets the screen position before it adds the notification panel and the app_bar_main.xml and moved the layout down which is absolutely ridiculous.  Changing to this line was part of the problem:`int centerY = posXY[1] + ((rootview.findViewById(R.id.iv_slider)).getHeight() / 2);`  How do I get the height of the notification panel from the system???

Comment: Ok, found a post about getting the height of the status bar which I will put into an answer soon.  Now I'm getting **Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getHeight()' on a null object reference** when i try to get the height of `R.id.toolbar`

Answer (score 0):

Well... this is a start.  Need to write more code to get orientation to add for onscreen system buttons when located on the left side.  There has to be an easier option than this...  I'm not going to mark this answered yet so I can see if anyone has a better answer for this.

I still need to account for the on screen hardware buttons when on the left side.

So to get height of the status bar use code:

```
//Get system's status bar height
public int getStatusBarHeight() {
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then convert the dp size of your toolbar height located in app_bar_main.xml:

```
    /**
 * This method converts dp unit to equivalent pixels, depending on device density.
 *
 * @param dp A value in dp (density independent pixels) unit. Which we need to convert into pixels
 * @param context Context to get resources and device specific display metrics
 * @return A float value to represent px equivalent to dp depending on device density
 */
public static float convertDpToPixel(float dp, Context context){
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float px = dp * ((float)metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
    return px;
}
```

Which you use in the following code:
(I made it universal for everyone, don't forget to change the value for the size of the toolbar in your app)

```
public void centerObjectToParent(View parent, View child){
    //ImageView joystickPosition = (ImageView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.iv_joystick_position);
    int posXY[] = new int[2];
    parent.getLocationInWindow(posXY);
    int centerX = posXY[0] + (parent.getWidth() / 2);
    int centerY = posXY[1] + (parent.getHeight() / 2);
    child.setX(centerX - (child.getWidth() / 2));
    child.setY(centerY - getStatusBarHeight() - convertDpToPixel(60, rootview.getContext()) - (child.getHeight() / 2));
}
```

I can't believe how difficult this turned out to be -_____-

Google needs to fix that get screen position code to get the actual screen position after placement.

Answer (score 0):

Using RelativeLayout with a background instead of ImageView seems to have avoided these issues but does not auto scale the image to the aspect ratio.

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/slider3"
    android:id="@+id/layout_slider"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"" />
```

I'd like to see a better answer if anyone has one.